# Tactics for analyzing data scraped from the web

Tags: c#, algorithm, parsing, user-experience

I'm working on an app and want to have a feature where the user can input a URL and the app will try to pull certain information from the page. I've already decided on [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for fetching and parsing the HTML itself and creating a DOM that's easy to traverse.  My hangup is trying to formulate a generic way to find the information I want from within that DOM.

For example, say the app is expecting the user to provide a URL to a product page of some sort and I want to parse out some information like price, model, etc.  I could always go the route of writing specialized code for expected major websites ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1815125/502390) answer touches on that) but the goal is not to specialize.  Some items can be pretty easily identified (e.g price) but some other information might be identified with more varied language (e.g SKU vs part number vs stock number vs item number etc.).

One thought I've had so far is to identify likely locations for each piece of information I'm trying to extract and if the confidence is low present a "preview" to the user and let them approve or reject it but I'm obviously looking to maximize confidence and minimize demand on the user.

A second thought would be to specialize on major sites and fall back to the generic algorithm as a catchall.  Could possibly collect anonymous user data to know which sites are most requested.

Comment: If you can get the name of a field (eg Price, SKU, etc) then you could simply show the user that info beside whatever product name they come after. You could even create a list of variations / synonyms / translations for common field names (eg price, cost, precio etc)